# Is there anything like "Beginning of file" in C?

Tags: c, text, processor

I need to make a "text processor" or "translator" (a VERY little and basic one). Its input is a text file with any text and I have to find roman numerals and replace them with another word. For example, in this text:

> Hello I am a text sayIIng stVffI

The output should be:

> Hello REPLACED_WORD am a text sayIIng stVffI

Meaning I need to replace only the words that are numerals, and not things that have numerals in them, for example sayIIng. It has II, but it's not just II so it doesn't "translate" it.

I'm doing this using fgets() to read the file, then strtok() to separate the words of each line, and strpbrk() to find every occurence of some string into another. My problem is if I have a correct roman numeral in the first letter of a text file, it doesn't recognize it 'cause the conditions are that the numeral has either a space, or a \n or a \t or NULL before... and it seems that none of those are before the numeral in the text file.

These are the functions that validate that the numerals are separate from the rest of the text/sentence.

```
int validate_before(char *token){
    char *tk = token-1;
    if(tk[0] == ' ' || tk[0] == '\t' || tk[0] == '\n' || tk[0] == 'NULL'){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int validate_after(char *token){
    char *tk = token+1;
    if(tk[0] == ' ' || tk[0] == '\t' || tk[0] == '\0' || tk[0] == EOF){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I have a function that reads the file and tries to find each occurence (still I'm trying to figuring out how to re-write the whole text with the words replaces but first things first).

```
while(fgets(buffer, 1024, archivo_entrada)){
            aux = strtok(buffer, "\n");
            while(aux != NULL){
                char *primera = strpbrk(aux, "I");

                printf("%s @@ \n", aux);
                while(primera != NULL){
                    if(primera && (validate_before(primera) == 1) && (validate_after(primera) == 1)){
                        printf("--FOUND AN "I"--\n");
                    }
                    primera = strpbrk(primera+1, "I");
                }
             aux = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to *Roman Numerals?*

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to know when a token is at the beginning of a line not the beginning of the file. Is that right?

Comment: Uh no, 'cause fgets() reads line to line, so if I have this txt:
"I \n
II \n
III"

it will recognize II and III cause there is a \n before them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot work in place, since files are byte sequences which can only be appended or truncated (at their end) - there is no elementary way to replace an internal sequence (inside, not at end, of some file) of bytes by another one (of different size).

So you need to read an input file, and write an output file (perhaps [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html)-ing it to the input if your want a program that replaces a file).

So you probably want to process the input file line by line; either with `fgets` (if you accept having a fixed line buffer which limits the widest line) or with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), at least on POSIX systems (it can accept arbitrary long lines fitting in memory)

To parse the line, you could parse it by hand (not using `strtok`), coding a simple [finite state automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) (if you wanted to, you could generate that automaton with [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/), but that is overkill). Alternatively, consider using [regex(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) (probably an overkill in your case)

BTW, beginning of file (not of line) condition is, using [ftell(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftell.3.html), just `ftell(`*file*`) == 0L`

There is no beginning of line condition or character. It is just when `aux == buffer` (with `aux` being the current character pointer, and `buf` being the line buffer)

Notice that [strtok(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) is stateful. If you insist using it, you should reset it by passing it a non `NULL` buffer the first time (at start of line), and passing it `NULL` the other times

Comment: Oh okay so first of all, I need to write an output file with the same txt but the roman numerals translated. And yes, I'm planning to do that line by line, but I don't know if I can use getline() 'cause I need it to be ran on Windows (particularly, compiled using Codeblocks).
I've actually never coded a finite state automation, but I could do some research on it, although strktok() is more familiar to me, any particular reason to not use it?
I'm wondering now, is there any BEGGINIG OF LINE character to check?
Thanks!

Comment: I gave it a little more thought and I don't think an automata is a viable option 'cause what I actually need to do is to find roman numerals from 1 to 13, meaning I'd have to check if I have I, II, III, XIII, etc... that's a lot of states.

Comment: finite automata programs have often a lot (thousands, or millions) of states, so they are generally generated. You don't need more than a few dozen of states, and that  is tiny